# can't read null value of the fillTrainingRoomsArray type

Tags: reactjs

I am sorry if it's long, but I want to fill array of training rooms where each room is an object that saves data of the room, however when i try to do that i get can't read null property error, though i call this function only when i press the submit button

```
const fillTrainingRoomsArray = () => {
    const trainingRoomsArray = Array.from(
      { length: TrainingRoomLength },
      (_, index) => {
        const roomName = document.getElementById(
          `trainingRoomName_${index + 1}`
        ).value;
        const roomPhotos = document
          .getElementById(`trainingRoomPhotos_${index + 1}`)
          .value.split(",");
        const capacity = parseInt(
          document.getElementById(`trainingRoomCapacity_${index + 1}`).value
        );
        const amenities = document.getElementById(
          `trainingRoomAmenities_${index + 1}`
        ).value;
        const description = document.getElementById(
          `trainingRoomDescription_${index + 1}`
        ).value;
        const price = parseFloat(
          document.getElementById(`trainingRoomPrice_${index + 1}`).value
        );

        return {
          roomName,
          roomPhotos,
          capacity,
          amenities,
          description,
          price,
        };
      }
    );

    console.log(trainingRoomsArray);
    return trainingRoomsArray; // Return the array if needed elsewhere in the code
  };


const handleTrainingRoomsChange = (e) => {
    const countTrain = Number(e.target.value);
    setNumberOfTrainingRooms(countTrain);
  };

{isTrainingRoom && (
                <Form.Group controlId="numberOfTrainingRooms">
                  <Form.Label>Number of Training Rooms</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control
                    type="number"
                    placeholder="Enter the Training Rooms number"
                    onChange={handleTrainingRoomsChange}
                  ></Form.Control>
                  {numberOfTrainingRooms <= 0 && (
                    <div>
                      You can't choose that number of meeting rooms if it's 0
                      please uncheck the room type above
                    </div>
                  )}
                </Form.Group>
              )}

              {trainingRoomInputs}
```

I know that it can happens if i call it before assigninig value, or when it has no value, but i didn't try to do any of that

Comment: *"can't read null property"* - Is this the **exact** text of the error?  (In the question title it's *"can't read null value"*... Which is it?  Or is it actually something else?)  Which specific line of code produces this error?

Comment: As an aside... Directly interacting with the DOM is *almost always* the wrong approach in React.  Why do you need to do this in the first place?  How are you using this code in React?  If you're using React, why isn't the data you're looking for in state rather than in the DOM?